# Parse JSON to Google Spreadsheet Python

Tags: python, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to call the Pairs Info from ShapeShift API to Google SpreadSheet.

I call: https://shapeshift.io/marketinfo/

which is supposed to return a JSON similar to this:

```
[
{
    "rate": "787.32227488",
    "limit": 0.74761076,
    "pair": "BTC_ICN",
    "maxLimit": 0.93451345,
    "min": 0.0004924,
    "minerFee": 0.2
},
{
    "rate": "0.00122699",
    "limit": 607.31986909,
    "pair": "ICN_BTC",
    "maxLimit": 759.14983636,
    "min": 3.15955766,
    "minerFee": 0.002
},
{
    "rate": "57.83625391",
    "limit": 0.74761076,
    "pair": "BTC_MLN",
    "maxLimit": 0.93451345,
    "min": 0.000102,
    "minerFee": 0.003
}
```

I want the data to populate my spreadsheet this way:

rate   limit   pair   maxLimit   min   minerFee
...     ...     ...    ....       ...    ...

Here what I have so far:

class Data(ShapeShiftAPI):
    def **init**(self):

```
    ShapeShiftAPI.__init__(self)

    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('config.json', scope)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

    wks = gc.open("data_test").sheet1

    cell_list = wks.range('A1')
    data = self.return_shapeshift_pairs_info()
    obj = json.loads(data)

    for cell in cell_list:
        cell.value = data
    wks.update_cells(cell_list)

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     app = Data()
```

If I do: **print(self.return_shapeshift_pairs_info())**

It returns all available ShapeShift coins symbols

But I can update it to my google spreadsheet. I need help how to get get the data to the right cell.

Thank you!

Comment: About `I need help how to get get the data to the right cell.`, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? Because I cannot know your Spreadsheet from your question. I apologize for this. For example, do you want to put your values by following the header row? Or, your Spreadsheet has no header row and you want to put your values by ignoring the header row? I think that the approach depends on your expected result. So, first, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get this done would be to install Python for Google Sheets:
https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/neptyne_python_for_sheets/891309878867

After you set it up, you can then define a python function like

```
def get_pairs():
    # call the shape shift api
    return data # as a list of lists
```

and then in your spreadsheet you can call this with

```
=Py("get_pairs")
```

and it shows the table in your google sheets